# Found nil while storyboard.instantiate

Tags: ios, firebase

I am building a renting app with firebase. I have a screen 'WelcomeViewController'.Now the functionality of this screen is that when app starts, it checks wether the user is logged in or not. If it is, then it perform storyboard instantiate to HomeScreenViewController and if user is logged out, then it should instantiate storyboard to LoginViewController. Now, the first part is running fine and storyboard does instantiate to HomeScreenViewController but during the second part when storyboard.instantiate is run, it crashes with error "found nil while force unwrapping optional". I have crosschecked all the storyboard ID's and everything. I cant seem to figure out.

import UIKit
import Firebase

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {

```
var docRef:DocumentReference!
var Uid:String?
var homeVC:UITabBarController? = nil



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        //User is signed in
        print("User is logged in")
        docRef = Firestore.firestore().document("Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
        docRef.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
            guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { print("Error Founddddd");return}
            let myData = docSnapshot.data()
            let type = myData?["Role"] as? String ?? ""
            print(type)

            if type == "Owner" {
                self.homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "OwnerHome") as? OwnerHomeTabBarViewController
                self.view.window?.rootViewController = self.homeVC
                self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            }
            else {
                self.homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TouristHome") as? TouristHomeTabBarViewController
                self.view.window?.rootViewController = self.homeVC
                self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }

    }

      else {
             print("User is loggedout")
            //Send User to Login/Signup Screen
        let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let LoginVC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "loginScreen") as! SignInViewController
        self.view.window!.rootViewController = LoginVC  //Error is coming here
        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()



        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Presumably `self.view.window` is `nil`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `!` from `self.view.window!` and replace with `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set storyboard ID in your Storyboard for each ViewController ?